# Adding Multiple jQuery UI Slider Values

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am using jQuery UI Slider - Range with fixed minimum.  My need is to take the value from one slider and add it with another slider value and display the result in a text box below.

The sliders are setup with:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-food" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 50,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      slide: function( event, ui1 ) {
        $( "#amountFood" ).val( ui1.value );
        total($( "#amountRent" ),ui1);
      }
    });
    $( "#slider-range-rent" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 50,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      slide: function( event, ui2 ) {
        $( "#amountRent" ).val( ui2.value );        
        total($( "#amountFood" ),ui2);
      }
    });

    $( "#amountFood" ).val( $( "#slider-range-food" ).slider( "value" ) );
    $( "#amountRent" ).val( $( "#slider-range-rent" ).slider( "value" ) );

  });
```

The function to total the values is:

```
  function total(ui1,ui2) {   
      $( "#amountTotal" ).val( ui1.val()  +  ui2.value );
  }
```

The html is:

```
<label for="amountFood">Expence For Food:</label>
<input type="text" name="amountFood" id="amountFood" class="text" value="50">
<input type="text" id="amountFood" readonly="readonly" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
<div id="slider-range-food"></div>

<label for="amountRent">Expence For Rent:</label>
<input type="text" name="amountRent" id="amountRent" class="text" value="50">
<input type="text" id="amountRent" readonly="readonly" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
<div id="slider-range-rent"></div>

<label for="amountTotal">Total Expence:</label>
<input type="text" name="amountTotal" id="amountTotal" class="text" value="50">
<input type="text" id="amountTotal" readonly="readonly" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to a jsfiddle for this:  http://jsfiddle.net/kytkL835/ 
(fixed version, see below, in http://jsfiddle.net/kytkL835/1/)

Running it, shows the issue:

$(el).val() from a text input will be a text value, so the `total` function is adding the values together as string, ie `"50" + 100 = "50100"`.

You need to convert the `.val()` from string to int, simply `*1` the val:

```
function total(el, slider) {   
    $( "#amountTotal" ).val((el.val() * 1) + slider.value);
}
```

(I've also renamed the args to your usage to make it clear why one is `.val()` and the other is `.value`).

As an aside, I would change the total() func to take int arguments, then it's not reliant on passing the correct types (jquery element + slider ui event value) and can be used outside the event if needed (eg on page load).